# Abinitio graph extract Information

Tags: ab-initio

I have an Abinitio graph with multiple subgraphs in it. I need to extract following information about the graphs: List of i/p files, o/p files, i/o tables, lookup files, run program, etc. How can I automate this process of extraction of all graphs without doing it manually on GDE.

Comment: The items sought are metadata. The EME/Metadata Hub is the repository of metadata.

Answer (score 2):

you can create the script and call below commands for details:

```
air sandbox get-required-files
air sandbox run $1 -script-only
```

Let me know if this resolves the issue.